# TScaledLayout anchor point

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In a form I have a Layout aligned as alContent and inside I have a new button aligned as alRight. The problem is when I reduce the scale, the direction is always from right to left. Is there any way to when I decrease the scale of the Layout the button continue right-aligned in relation to the Form changing the direction of left to right?

[image]

Comment: Is there any way you could clarify your issue? Perhaps with a screenshot or two?

Comment: @David Heffernan: I'd put some cents on "alContent = alClient".

Comment: @Sherlock70, it's not properly tagged, but I bet it's the FMX's [`TAlignLayout`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/FMX.Types.TAlignLayout) enumeration member.

Comment: I put a picture to better explain
@DavidHeffernanm

Comment: Any ideia @JerryDodge? I dont believe this is not possible...

Comment: @RomuloPehls You should put pictures in your question using StackOverflow's built-in picture tool. Users hate clicking third-party links like the one you have above. I'd be shocked if your reputation prevents you from adding images. Otherwise, sorry I don't know how to help you - hopefully someone else does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that is not a definitive solution but so far I haven't found another alternative  to reposition the TScaledLayout proportionally when I change the scale.

```
procedure TForm1.TrackBar1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with ScaledLayout1
  do Position.X := OriginalWidth - (OriginalWidth / (1 / TrackBar1.Value));
end;
```